# How to make different headings on even and odd pages

Tags: fancyhdr, bookmarks

I want to make some headings on my thesis.

I use the following codes in my cls file.

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\thechapter. #1 }}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhead{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}
```

However only a line appear in the upperspace of the pages and no headings. So i try to use

```
\markboth{aaaa}{bbbb}
```

Then the headings appear. But what i want is "aaaa" appears on every odd page and "bbb" appears on every even page

Comment: If i use markboth as above then only "bbbb" appearing on every page.

Answer (score 6):

Note that you can use different headers on odd and even pages only if your document class is loaded with the `twoside` option.

For example, if you have:

```
\documentclass{book}
\fancyhead[RO]{aaaa}
\fancyhead[LE]{bbbb}
```

then `aaaa` is printed on the right side of odd pages and `bbbb` is printed on the left side of even pages. This because the document class `book` is automatically loaded with the `twoside` option.

If you want to achieve the same result with document classes such as `report`, you have to explicitly load them with the `twoside` option. E.g.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\fancyhead[RO]{aaaa}
\fancyhead[LE]{bbbb}
```

Also note that, an empty redefinition of `\sectionmark` causes `\markright` to be empty as well, so, unless you change it, you will have no header in odd pages.