# Header on even or odd pages

Tags: header-footer, double-sided

Hi everyone I have been trying to create a different header for even or odd pages where I want to see the name of the section and the name of subsections. This is what I have done but it is not working.

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}    
\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}    

\section{Introduction}    
\newpage

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}    
\setcounter{section}{0}

\pagenumbering{arabic}    
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhf{}    
\fancyfoot{}    
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}    
\fancyhead[LO]{\small\nouppercase\leftmark}    
\fancyhead[RE]{\small\rightmark}    

\section{First Section}    
\newpage     
\subsection{First subsection}    
\newpage        
\subsection{Second subsection}    
\newpage       
\section{Second Section}
\newpage     
\subsection{First subsection}    
\newpage    
\subsection{Second subsection}

\end{document}
```

This is pretty much my example, I would like to see something like this: On even pages the name of the section, and on odd pages the name of the subsection, but I am having the same result always. Only the name of the section appears, and the numeration is not located according with the kind of page (even or odd).

What else do I need to add or erase?.

Comment: Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Does this answer of mine help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122383/27635

Comment: The [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) should start with `\documentclass{...}`...

Answer (score 2):

Your MWE seems to give what you are asking for if you add `\documentclass[english, twoside]{article}` to the beginning. The `twoside` option is necessary in order to have different even and odd sides.

Answer (score 1):

The [`titleps` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/titleps) provides similar functionality to that of [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr). Here's an implementation using the former which specifies a new `main` page style using

```
\newpagestyle{main}[\small]{
  \setheadrule{.4pt}%
  \sethead[\thepage]%                             even-left
          []%                                     even-center
          [\thesection\ \sectiontitle]%           even-right
          {\thesubsection\ \subsectiontitle}%     odd-left
          {}%                                     odd-center
          {\thepage}%                             odd-right
  }
```

Also see [`titleps` for `fancyhdr` users](http://www.tex-tipografia.com/titleps_fancyhdr.html) for the similarities/transition between the two packages.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{titleps}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titleps

\newpagestyle{main}[\small]{
  \setheadrule{.4pt}%
  \sethead[\thepage]%                             even-left
          []%                                     even-center
          [\thesection\ \sectiontitle]%           even-right
          {\thesubsection\ \subsectiontitle}%     odd-left
          {}%                                     odd-center
          {\thepage}%                             odd-right
  }
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}    

\section{Introduction}    
\newpage

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}    
\setcounter{section}{0}

\pagenumbering{arabic}    
\pagestyle{main}

\section{First Section}    
\newpage     
\subsection{First subsection}    
\newpage        
\subsection{Second subsection}    
\newpage       
\section{Second Section}
\newpage     
\subsection{First subsection}    
\newpage    
\subsection{Second subsection}

\end{document}
```